# PHP submit to database when validated

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I have been working on a form to add data to the database. I have validation which let's the user know if a field is empty or is invalid. Once all is validated I want to submit it to the database. My current code validates data but submits regardless. This is probably a flaw in my logic and if else statements but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is part of the code including some validation and the INSERT statement.

```
// Quantity

if (empty($_POST["qtyAdd"]))
    {
    $qtyErr = "Please enter a product quantity";
    }
  else
if (!is_numeric($year))
    {
    $qtyErr = "Data entered was not numeric";
    }
  else
if (strlen($number) != 3)
    {
    $qtyErr = "The number entered was not 3 digits long";
    }
  else
    {
    $qty = test_input($_POST["yearAdd"]);
    }

// Featured

if (empty($_POST["featuredAdd"]))
    {
    $featuredErr = "Feature Item?";
    }
  else
    {
    $featured = test_input($_POST["featuredAdd"]);
    }

//Add to database

    {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_products (product_name, product_description, product_price, product_year, product_show, product_type, product_signed, product_quantity, product_featured, product_img) VALUES ('$name', '$desc', '$price', '$year', '$show', '$cat', '$signed', '$qty', '$featured', $img)";
    mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not bothering to check if there is an error. That's why your query is always executed:

```
if (!isset($qtyErr) && !isset($featuredErr)) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_products (product_name, product_description, product_price, product_year, product_show, product_type, product_signed, product_quantity, product_featured, product_img) VALUES ('$name', '$desc', '$price', '$year', '$show', '$cat', '$signed', '$qty', '$featured', $img)";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: One more question. As I have done this: $qtyErr = $featuredErr = ""; to make sure there are no errors, the Err is always set, is there something other than !isset I can use which will work with this method?

Comment: You can use `empty()`. An empty string will be true, if there is an error message in there it will be false. `if (empty($qtyErr) && empty($featuredErr)) {`